# Javascript - BYTES_PER_ELEMENT is undefined in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera, arraybuffer

I'm trying to write some application using ArrayBuffers, Websockets and [DataStream.js](https://github.com/kig/DataStream.js) library, but it is failing on pretty simple code and I haven't found any related pages about same problem.

The problem is that

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(6);
alert(arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
```

Returns undefined. I can use directly `Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` (which is in Opera 1), but DataStream.js library is using "universal" way to get this property: (DataStream.js:377)

```
DataStream.memcpy(arr.buffer, 0,
                this.buffer, this.byteOffset+this.position,
                length*arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
```

Is there some way to keep it universal but working in Opera 12? Something like `arr.__proto__.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`.

Or am I doing something wrong? In Chromium it works OK.

Comment: well, if `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` is undefined, chances are you're going to have to use some default definition of your own as a fallback. Since Opera is based on chromium _possibly_ it could be safe to use the same value but nothing is certain of course.

Comment: in [this](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/de/home?&property=Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT) listing it claims Opera does have the constant defined. What version are you using?

Comment: Opera 12 is not based on chromium. Opera 12 is last version released for linux. Exact version I use is linux x86_64 12.16

Comment: The web displays only `Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`, not `arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`, where `arr` is instanceof Uint8Array

Comment: Ahh you're using old opera. Well the listing reports it's a `number` on opera 12.17. Also, if `arr` is an instance of `Uint8Array` it should have that member.

Comment: I'm using old, though newest Opera :)

Comment: well on opera 23 for winxp it works out-of-the-box. It seems like this should never happen and that it isn't a version problem. Your version _should_ have it defined. Perhaps it's a scope issue. Maybe some peculiarity due to browser or page scope or something. I can't think of anything else. Unless ofcourse, some library is _redefining_ `Uint8Array`.

Comment: ooooh wait, you _can_ access it directly and it's only through datastream.js that it fails? Why not just `var bytezor = Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` and then use `bytezor` in your datastream.js call?

Comment: Opera 23 is much more chrome than Opera. Now, I tried it with simplest HTML page without libraries etc and it is still undefined. `<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><script>var a = new Uint8Array(6); alert(a.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);</script></body></html>`

Comment: thats very very weird. in what case _could_ you use it directly as you state in the OP?

Comment: The only way to display correct value is to use name of the function: `alert(Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT); var a = new Uint8Array(6); alert(a.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);` displays two msgboxes: first with "1", second with "undefined". Chromium displays two times "1".

Comment: Hmm then apparently it seems that version of opera does _not_ have the same object inheritance model for `Uint8Array` or something is going very wrong (or the constructor just doesn't link that property when making your new instance). In any case, since this is a constant, I'd say it's ok to just get it directly from `Uint8Array` and trust that value. Any reason why that wouldn't work? Also, try `alert(a instanceof Unit8Array)`.

Comment: [this](https://code.google.com/p/cwebgl/issues/detail?id=13) also shows some peculiar constructor behavior, though it doesn't mention the opera version he was testing on.

Comment: `a instanceof Uint8Array == true`. Good to see, that I'm not the only facing this problem. Now I'm going to do some ugly pseudohacking this behaviour. Thx for your time!

Comment: no problem :) if you do find some resolution, it would be good to answer your own question and accept it, just so this is closed (unless you want to keep it open). Also, it might still be good to post whatever solution you finally end up with (no need for detailed code, just a description). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after short discussion with ivy_lynx, I decided to do it this simple way, which sets value that should be set in prototypes. Now the DataStream.js library works OK even in Opera 12.16

```
if (Uint8Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT == undefined) {
    Uint8Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Uint8ClampedArray.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Uint8ClampedArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Int8Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Int8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Uint16Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Uint16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Int16Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Uint32Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Int32Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
    Float64Array.prototype.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; 
}
```